# How can I create List of Lists and add to it items and then read back the items?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In the top of class

```
public static List<string> countriescodes = new List<string>();
public static List<string> countriesnames = new List<string>();
public static List<List<string>> imagesUrls = new List<List<string>>();
```

In class constructor

```
public void Init()
{
    if (!File.Exists(@"c:\temp\countriesandcodes.txt"))
    {
         w = new StreamWriter(@"c:\temp\countriesandcodes.txt");
    }
    else
    {
         lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"c:\temp\countriesandcodes.txt");
    }

    foreach (string countrycode in lines)
    {
         if (countrycode.Contains("Code"))
         {
             string code = countrycode.Substring(15);
             countriescodes.Add(code);
         }
         else
         {
             string code = countrycode.Substring(15);
             countriesnames.Add(code);
         }
    }

    foreach (string cc in countriescodes)
    {
         ExtractDateAndTime("http://www.sat24.com/image2.ashx?region=" + cc);
    }
    ImagesLinks();
}
```

Then in ImagesLinks

```
public void ImagesLinks()
{
     int cnt = 0;
     foreach (string countryCode in countriescodes)
      {
          cnt++;
          for (; cnt < DatesAndTimes.Count(); cnt++)
          {
              string imageUrlIrTrue = firstUrlPart + countryCode + secondUrlPart + DatesAndTimes[cnt] + thirdUrlPart + "true";
              string imageUrlIrFalse = firstUrlPart + countryCode + secondUrlPart + DatesAndTimes[cnt] + thirdUrlPart + "false";
              imagesUrls.Add(imageUrlIrTrue);
              imagesUrls.Add(imageUrlIrFalse);
              if (cnt % 10 == 0) break;
           }
      }
 }
```

In the `imagesUrls` I want to add each `countryName` to a List.
For example in `imagesUrls` I will have the first List in this format: The first item in each List will be the country name and then to build the links from the countries codes list of each country name.

```
Turkey

link1
link2
.
.
.
link9
```

Then ext `Lis`t in `imagesUrls` will be

```
Europe

link1
link2
.
.
.
link9
```

What I want is to create Lists in `imagesUrl`s and each List will contain at the top first the country name from the `countriesnames` List then the links for this country using the `countriescodes` List using the `imageUrlIrTrue` and `imageUrlIrFalse`

Then in `Form1` I want to read each `List` and the items of each `List`.

This is a part of the file countriesandcodes.txt to see how it's formatted:
What i want to do in general is to use this class in form1 so i can easy get each country and it's all links using the both lists countriescodes and countriesnames.

```
Country Code = eu
Country Name = Europe
Country Code = alps
Country Name = Alps
Country Code = nl
Country Name = Benelux
Country Code = de
Country Name = Germany
Country Code = sp
Country Name = Spain & Portugal
Country Code = fr
Country Name = France
```

This is the complete code of the class. Maybe it will be easier to look at it like this.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Xml;
using HtmlAgilityPack;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace SatelliteImages
{
    class ExtractImages
    {
        static WebClient client;
        static string htmltoextract;
        public static List<string> countriescodes = new List<string>();
        public static List<string> countriesnames = new List<string>();
        public static List<string> DatesAndTimes = new List<string>();
        public static List<List<string>> imagesUrls = new List<List<string>>();

        static string firstUrlPart = "http://www.sat24.com/image2.ashx?region=";
        static string secondUrlPart = "&time=";
        static string thirdUrlPart = "&ir=";
        StreamWriter w;
        string[] lines;

        public bool WebProblem = false;

        public void Init()
        {
            if (!File.Exists(@"c:\temp\countriesandcodes.txt"))
            {
                w = new StreamWriter(@"c:\temp\countriesandcodes.txt");
            }
            else
            {
                lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"c:\temp\countriesandcodes.txt");
            }

            foreach (string countrycode in lines)
            {
                if (countrycode.Contains("Code"))
                {
                    string code = countrycode.Substring(15);
                    countriescodes.Add(code);
                }
                else
                {
                    string code = countrycode.Substring(15);
                    countriesnames.Add(code);
                }
            }

            foreach (string cc in countriescodes)
            {
                ExtractDateAndTime("http://www.sat24.com/image2.ashx?region=" + cc);
            }
            ImagesLinks();
        }     

        public void ExtractCountires()
        {
            try
            {
                htmltoextract = "http://sat24.com/en/?ir=true";//"http://sat24.com/en/";// + regions;
                client = new WebClient();
                client.DownloadFile(htmltoextract, @"c:\temp\sat24.html");
                client.Dispose();

                string tag1 = "<li><a href=\"/en/";
                string tag2 = "</a></li>";

                string s = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"c:\temp\sat24.html");
                s = s.Substring(s.IndexOf(tag1));
                s = s.Substring(0, s.LastIndexOf(tag2) + tag2.ToCharArray().Length);
                s = s.Replace("\r", "").Replace("\n", "").Replace(" ", "");

                string[] parts = s.Split(new string[] { tag1, tag2 }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);


                string tag3 = "<li><ahref=\"/en/";

                for (int i = 0; i < parts.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (i == 40)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    string l = "";
                    if (parts[i].Contains(tag3))
                        l = parts[i].Replace(tag3, "");

                    if (i == 39)
                    {
                        string fff = "";
                    }
                    string z1 = l.Substring(0, l.IndexOf('"'));
                    if (z1.Contains("</ul></li><liclass="))
                    {
                        z1 = z1.Replace("</ul></li><liclass=", "af");
                    }
                    countriescodes.Add(z1);
                    countriescodes.GroupBy(n => n).Any(c => c.Count() > 1);

                    string z2 = parts[i].Substring(parts[i].LastIndexOf('>') + 1);
                    if (z2.Contains("&amp;"))
                    {
                        z2 = z2.Replace("&amp;", " & ");
                    }
                    countriesnames.Add(z2);
                    countriesnames.GroupBy(n => n).Any(c => c.Count() > 1);
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < countriescodes.Count; i++)
                {
                    w.WriteLine("Country Code = " + countriescodes[i]);
                    w.WriteLine("Country Name = " + countriesnames[i]);
                }
                w.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                if (countriescodes.Count == 0)
                {
                    /*countriescodes = new List<string>();
                    countriesnames = new List<string>();
                    DatesAndTimes = new List<string>();
                    imagesUrls = new List<string>();
                    Init();*/
                }
            }
        }

        public void ExtractDateAndTime(string baseAddress)
        {
            try
            {
                var wc = new WebClient();
                wc.BaseAddress = baseAddress;
                HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();

                var temp = wc.DownloadData("/en");
                doc.Load(new MemoryStream(temp));

                var secTokenScript = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants()
                    .Where(e =>
                           String.Compare(e.Name, "script", true) == 0 &&
                           String.Compare(e.ParentNode.Name, "div", true) == 0 &&
                           e.InnerText.Length > 0 &&
                           e.InnerText.Trim().StartsWith("var region")
                          ).FirstOrDefault().InnerText;
                var securityToken = secTokenScript;
                securityToken = securityToken.Substring(0, securityToken.IndexOf("arrayImageTimes.push"));
                securityToken = secTokenScript.Substring(securityToken.Length).Replace("arrayImageTimes.push('", "").Replace("')", "");
                var dates = securityToken.Trim().Split(new string[] { ";" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                var scriptDates = dates.Select(x => new ScriptDate { DateString = x });
                foreach (var date in scriptDates)
                {
                    DatesAndTimes.Add(date.DateString);
                }
            }
            catch(WebException wex)
            {
                WebProblem = true;
            }
        }

        public class ScriptDate
        {
            public string DateString { get; set; }
            public int Year
            {
                get
                {
                    return Convert.ToInt32(this.DateString.Substring(0, 4));
                }
            }
            public int Month
            {
                get
                {
                    return Convert.ToInt32(this.DateString.Substring(4, 2));
                }
            }
            public int Day
            {
                get
                {
                    return Convert.ToInt32(this.DateString.Substring(6, 2));
                }
            }
            public int Hours
            {
                get
                {
                    return Convert.ToInt32(this.DateString.Substring(8, 2));
                }
            }
            public int Minutes
            {
                get
                {
                    return Convert.ToInt32(this.DateString.Substring(10, 2));
                }
            }
        }

        public void ImagesLinks()
        {
            int cnt = 0;
            foreach (string countryCode in countriescodes)
            {
                cnt++;
                for (; cnt < DatesAndTimes.Count(); cnt++)
                {
                    string imageUrlIrTrue = firstUrlPart + countryCode + secondUrlPart + DatesAndTimes[cnt] + thirdUrlPart + "true";
                    string imageUrlIrFalse = firstUrlPart + countryCode + secondUrlPart + DatesAndTimes[cnt] + thirdUrlPart + "false";
                    imagesUrls.Add(imageUrlIrTrue);
                    imagesUrls.Add(imageUrlIrFalse);
                    if (cnt % 10 == 0) break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to add a class now to the class

```
public class Country
        {
            public List<Tuple<Uri, bool>> URLList { get; set; }
            public string Code { get; set; }
        }
```

Not sure how to use the property Code.
And i added a bool to the List since i want to make that when i loop over the list in form1 i will have links of true and false like i did in the ImagesLinks method:

```
string imageUrlIrTrue = firstUrlPart + countryCode + secondUrlPart + DatesAndTimes[cnt] + thirdUrlPart + "true";
string imageUrlIrFalse = firstUrlPart + countryCode + secondUrlPart + DatesAndTimes[cnt] + thirdUrlPart + "false";
```

But maybe instead using bool in the List and make it Tuple i should change it back to List and use the bool in other way to build the links.

In general i want that in form1 i will be able to get to 3 parameters:

1. The images links.
2. The countries codes.
3. The links should be true and false not bool but as part of the link for example:

imageUrlIrTrue:

http://www.sat24.com/image2.ashx?region=is&time=201701161900&ir=true

And false:

http://www.sat24.com/image2.ashx?region=is&time=201701161900&ir=false

And each country have 9 links built of the country code and date and time.
So in form1 i should have something like a List with Lists.
For example the class Country should have a property that if i type for example in form1: Country.Country.Turkey

And then i should i have somehow also the 9 links of turkey and the code of turkey.

It's not only to get countries and codes but also each 9 links fro each country in fact 18 links each country since each link is double true/false.

So each country have 18 links !!! and i should be able to access them in a loop in form1 and also to access the countries codes and names.

So in form1 i should have a loop that i can easy get the countries names get each country 18 links( true and false ) and each country code !!!

Comment: Since we don't know what `countriesandcodes.txt` looks like, it is hard to give a good answer. From what you have posted about your problem... I agree with @Gavin Perkins it looks like a class would come in handy.

Comment: If there any reason your `countriesandcodes.txt` file isn't in a standard, well-known format (like XML or JSON)?

Comment: @DanielMann Not a real reason. I just when created the file added country then code. I can change it to add to my question the part that create the file. I'm not creating the file any more it was created only once.

Comment: @DanielDejunior can you make the text file pipe or comma delimited? (example:
fr|france
us|United States
)

Comment: I changed the text file it's now csv type: Europe,eu
Alps,alps
Benelux,nl
Germany,de
Spain & Portugal,sp
France,fr
Greece,gr
Italy,it
Poland,pl
Scandinavia,scan

Comment: Link for the file: http://textuploader.com/ddnyv

Comment: @GavinPerkins here is a link for the file you can see the format: http://textuploader.com/ddnyv

Answer (score 3):

This may not technically be the answer, but the better approach here is to create a class called "Country" and give it properties for url, country name,  etc. Then you only need to create a list(of country) and populate each.

**Note to Daniel d e junior
(I will edit this with a code example if you can provide me with what countriesandcodes.txt looks like)

Comment: I added now to my question at the bottom a part of the countriesandcodes.txt so you can how it looks like how it formatted.

Comment: That is technically and strategically the right answer, having classes will make this question much clearer.

Answer (score 1):

> What I want is to create Lists in imagesUrls and each List will contain at the top first the country name from the countriesnames List then the links for this country using the countriescodes List using the imageUrlIrTrue and imageUrlIrFalse

Not sure what does "What I want is to create Lists in imagesUrls" actually means.

My question is why do you want do this? What you really need to do is use first programming, except you will need to think what classes you need.

Here is an example :
Let's say you have a list of image url's for each country

```
class Country
{
  List<URL> URLList;
}
```

also country has a country code

```
class Country
{
  public List<URL> URLList{get;set;}
  public string Code {get;set;}
}
```

Now you can grab a country and loop trough it's url's.
Try to use some classes and modify your question, ping me on update and I'll modify this answer to match the question.

Comment: I updated my question with what i did tried and what i need it to do. In general i need that in form1 i will be able with a loop to get all the countries names all the countries codes and each country links. Each country should have 18 links since each link is also true and also false when i build them. So each country have 18 links of images.

Comment: For example i will make a loop in form1 like this: For(int i = 0; i < ExtractImages.Country.Turkey.count(); i++) something like this and in the loop i will get somehow all the 18 links of Turkey all the links will be false and true 18 links. Same if i will make loop on each country. And also to be able to loop over some countries at once or all over the countries in one loop and get the links of all the countries. Since in some cases i will want to get the links of one country only but in other case to get links of other countries at once.

Comment: For example first i want to loop over only one country links: Turkey. Then i want to loop over the rest of the countries and get all the links of this countries in one loop.

Comment: @DanielDejunior : Instead of thinking the things you want to do, think about what are the things in your system, each "Thing" should become a class of it's own, then we can break it up and do it as an Object Oriented programming exercise.